# Proper use of Output Buffer

Tags: php, theme-development, functions

I'm attempting to use actions to override function calls I currently have throughout a template (to make updating certain replicated sections easier). For example, in `archives.php` I have the following:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php roots_content_before(); ?>
    <?php $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); if ($page_for_posts) { echo '<h1>' . get_the_title($page_for_posts) . '</h1>'; } ?>
    <h3>
        <?php
            $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
            if ($term) {
                echo $term->name;
            } elseif (is_day()) {
                printf(__('Daily Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date());
            } elseif (is_month()) {
                printf(__('Monthly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('F Y'));
            } elseif (is_year()) {
                printf(__('Yearly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('Y'));
            } elseif (is_author()) {
                global $post;
                $author_id = $post->post_author;
                printf(__('Author Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author_id));
            } else {
                single_cat_title();
            }
        ?>
    </h3>
    <?php echo category_description(); ?>
    <?php roots_loop_before(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('loop', 'category'); ?>
    <?php roots_loop_after(); ?>
    <?php roots_content_after(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You can see a few of the functions, like `roots_content_before();` In a separate file, I have the following:

`function roots_content_before() { do_action('roots_content_before'); }`

and use it as follows:

```
<?php

    add_action('roots_content_before', 'roots_bootstrap_content_before');

    function roots_bootstrap_content_before() { ?>

        this is some text

    <?php }

?>
```

From what I've read, especially if I'm going to have large chunks of code, I should be using the output buffer, but when I try to do this, I'm getting diddly squat:

```
<?php

    add_action('roots_content_before', 'roots_bootstrap_content_before');

    function roots_bootstrap_content_before() { ob_start(); ?> 

        this is some text

       <?php return ob_get_clean();

    }

?>
```

Am I thinking of this completely wrong? I am still learning, but have been trying for a bit without any success. Any pointers in the right direction would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you don’t need output buffering in this case. As a rule of thumb: Don’t use output buffering unless you really have to.

Just imagine what happens if someone else uses output buffering too from a plugin and it crosses with yours:

```
// plugin
ob_start();

// later, you in your theme
ob_start();

// you call a function where the plugin author hooked in to call:
print ob_get_clean();

// you call *your*:
return ob_get_clean();

// is is empty!
```

This is really hard to debug. Avoid it.

---

You don’t need a separate function to cover a plain `do_action()`. Just write `do_action('roots_content_before');` in your theme.

Comment: Agree with toscho here. Don't use Output Buffering. Use action and filter calls where needed.

Comment: Hi @toscho I really appreciate the input. I had only started to [read](http://dev-tips.com/featured/output-buffering-for-web-developers-a-beginners-guide) about output buffering, but from that article, it sounded like there was a performance increase. Whether there actually is or not, it almost sounds like if you are controlling the entire application then it would be good, but since WordPress has thousands of plugins, you just might be asking for trouble ;) Thanks again!

Comment: @Zach This article is wrong from the first line. :) Send your output to the user as soon as possible. In themes with long working code I even call [`flush()`](http://www.php.net/flush) before and after the slow code to speed the rendering up.

Comment: The bastards! ;)

Appreciate the further insight into that @toscho

Comment: [Progressive rendering via multiple flushes](http://www.phpied.com/progressive-rendering-via-multiple-flushes/) is a good read.

Comment: toscho, you can have nested output buffers. It's not a good thing to lose control over though :)

Comment: @offroff In WP somebody else may add an unwanted nesting. Therefore, don't use it in plugins or themes.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. It ignores situations in which you can use OB just fine. For example you have a function that outputs some HTML, and you want to return that HTML. As long as you don't fire common actions or call WP functions like get_header() in it, you should use OB to produce more readable code.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Depending on the exact operations you run earlier into memory limit with output buffering because … well … everything is stored in memory until `ob_end_clean()` is called. If you really need it tough – use it. That's what I said in my answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

@toscho's answer is totally wrong.

- [Output buffering can be nested](http://chipersoft.com/p/Nested-PHP-Output-Buffers/), there's **no need** to worry about other Plugins.
- In [this post from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818089/1255674) there's a very elegant way to fetch and manipulate the final output of Wordpress.

Comment: This is a bit harsh. I think what @toscho tried to say isn't that you can't nest, but that if for some reason you call `ob_get_clean()` before the code of e.g. another plugin which started the first `ob_start()` calls `ob_get_clean()` you'll get unexpected results. He just warns that you should really only use it if there is no other way as there are drawbacks which you might not notice at first.

Comment: Did you look at the second link? There's a nice handling that addresses exactly the problem of this question. There's nothing unexpected when nesting; try it yourself: `ob_start();
  echo "0";
  ob_start();
   echo "a";
  echo ob_get_clean();
  echo "1";
 $a = ob_get_clean();
 echo $a;`

Comment: To be honest - no I didn't. Again all I am saying is that there are a lot of ways to f*** this up, so better only use it when there is no other way. On a sidenote: This is the exact reason why link-only answers are frowned upon here. If you had added the gist of your links to the answer that would have helped a lot.