# Shortcode adding plugin output before post, instead of inline

Tags: shortcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcode always displaying at the top of the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48491/shortcode-always-displaying-at-the-top-of-the-page)

I have a quick and dirty shortcode which outputs a form in my wordpress pages. However, it adds the shortcode output at the beginning of my page, instead of inline where I want it.

For example:

```
(WordPress post:)
This is some text!
[shortcode_here]
This is more text!

(output)
The end result does this:
Shortcode output is showing up here!
This is some text!
This is more text!
```

The shortcode function is simply pulling some info. from a database and echoing the formatted results, a la:

```
   function shortcode_output() {
      //get stuff from database
      //format stuff
      echo <<<FORM
      <form method="POST" action="blah.php">
      <!--more html-->
      </form>
   FORM;
   }
```

I tried returning the content instead of echoing, but that simply shows up as a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return html instead of echoing it. Buffer output withing your function and return it:

```
function shortcode_output() {
    ob_start();
    //get stuff from database
    //format stuff
    echo <<<FORM
    <form method="POST" action="blah.php">
    <!--more html-->
    </form>
FORM;

    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the ob functions. That's perfect.

Comment: @TomThorogood you are welcome

Comment: [Avoid output buffering](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41012/proper-use-of-output-buffer/41014#41014). Just don’t use echo.