# How to overlay a webcomic plugin on top of a header image?

Tags: plugins, headers, header-image

I'm trying to build a (visually) simple webcomic site using the [Hestia](https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Hestia) theme. I'd like to replace the text and links in the center of the banner image (the text that reads "Slick Material Design
Beautiful, Elegantly Coded, One-Page WordPress Theme for Business" followed by a button that says "Read More") with the webcomic. The webcomic plugin I'm using is [comic easel](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/comic-easel/#installation), and the comic itself is summoned by adding the following code in the editor:

```
<?php do_action('comic-area'); ?>
```

If I just throw that into the header file, it'll shove the image down and sit by itself between the image and the menu bar. How would I go about sticking it in the center of the image?

Not new to programming but am new to programming for the web. Help here would be greatly appreciated as this is the only bit of custom work I really need to do before I can proceed. Thanks!

Comment: This could simply be a CSS question, or possibly php/html + CSS question. IOW once the needed content is being implanted in area, you can usually move it anywhere you like with CSS, in whatever dimensions, and with or without whatever other elements re-arranged to taste - but the whole thing might go cleaner if you modify the header file or other underlying code to facilitate.

Answer (score 0):

Is the  *"Slick Material Design Beautiful.."* content in a wsywig editor somewhere? the plugin doesn't come with any shortcodes though you could create one for:

```
<?php do_action('comic-area'); ?>
```

And use it in the editor where the default content is?

You can create shortcodes from actions though you will need to output buffer it, example: [Using action hooks inside of a shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59615/using-action-hooks-inside-of-a-shortcode)