# Adding content to a taxonomy metabox

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, metabox

I want to add some custom content to the default metabox for a custom taxonomy. Ideally I'd be able to insert this content above the tag cloud where it says ***Choose from the most used [tag]s***.

Is there a "best practice"-compliant way to do this in Wordpress? For example, is there a way to do this *without* removing and re-adding a clone of the taxonomy metabox, which is the method I've seen recommended for similar situations on WPSE and elsewhere? That seems like a bit of a blunt approach in this case.

I know I can insert the content with javascript, or use a separate metabox, but I'm wondering if there's a hook for this sort of task.

Answer (score 1):

From core:

```
function post_tags_meta_box($post, $box) {
    $defaults = array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag');
    if ( !isset($box['args']) || !is_array($box['args']) )
        $args = array();
    else
        $args = $box['args'];
    extract( wp_parse_args($args, $defaults), EXTR_SKIP );
    $tax_name = esc_attr($taxonomy);
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
    $disabled = !current_user_can($taxonomy->cap->assign_terms) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '';
    $comma = _x( ',', 'tag delimiter' );
?>
<div class="tagsdiv" id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>">
    <div class="jaxtag">
    <div class="nojs-tags hide-if-js">
    <p><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->add_or_remove_items; ?></p>
```

As you can see, there is no hook. So the only options are JavaScript or a clone of the metabox.

Third option: [Open a Trac ticket](http://codex.wordpress.org/Reporting_Bugs) and ask for a new hook.

You could also use output buffering, but I [don’t recommend that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41014/73), especially on that page.