# Separate tags with semicolon

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, wp-admin

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the callback function for a tag-like custom taxonomy so that it breaks terms after a semicolon instead of a comma? I realize I can [rewrite the whole meta box,](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78018/adding-content-to-a-taxonomy-metabox) but I'd rather not if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag delimiter is [made translatable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7897):

```
$comma = _x( ',', 'tag delimiter' );
```

So this can be changed with a simple filter:

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 't5_semicolon_tag_delimiter', 10, 4 );

function t5_semicolon_tag_delimiter( $translated, $text, $context, $domain )
{
    if ( 'default' !== $domain or 'tag delimiter' !== $context or ',' !== $text )
        return $translated;

    return ';';
}
```

Install [as plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web); works without any side effects.

What is tricky: changing the string *Separate tags with commas* to say *semicolon*. You cannot use the same solution, because you don’t know the language of your users. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: This still will not work, because of these two lines in the `wp_set_post_terms` function: `$tags = str_replace( $comma, ',', $tags ); $tags = explode( ',', trim( $tags, " \n\t\r\0\x0B," ) );`. **No matter what you do**, at some point the underlying WordPress code will force your tags to be delimited by commas.