# Using ob_get_content to get_search_form puts into infinite loop

Tags: plugin-development, filters, search

I am trying to change the look of my searchform. It basically needs to have two text fields. I want this to be in form of a plugin, which anyone can activate. SO obviously I do not have any control over `searchform.php`. And I also read that if searchform.php is present, then echo parameter is ignored (`http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Notes`)

This made me look at the code snippet under the heading "MOAR OBJECT BUFFERZ!!!" at:

`http://shinraholdings.com/363/3-wordpress-hacks-to-unlock-some-much-needed-features/4/`

I copied the code as it is and added a filter like:
`add_filter('get_search_form','shinra_searchform');`

However, the code seems to go in an infinite loop. I put an echo statement after lines 11 and 12. The one after 12 never gets printed while the one after line 11 keeps on getting printed continously.

I tried changing the filter to pass the argument to:

1. `add_filter('get_search_form',shinra_searchform(true),1);`
2. `add_filter('get_search_form',shinra_searchform(false),1);`
3. `add_filter('get_search_form',shinra_searchform($echo),1);`

But none of these work.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no safe way to catch the content of a `searchform.php` in this case. You could run output buffering on the complete page, but then you would probably run into [conflicts with other plugins doing the same](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41014/73).

Alternative solution: Add a widget to your plugin that offers another search form. Ask your users to use that instead of the built-in widget or theme search form.

Some themes use a hard coded call to `get_search_form()` – there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot toscho. Yes, I have been searching over the porums for past 3 days, but to no avail. The only hope was a post hat mentioned the use of this hack of o/p buffering. But as you mentioned that might be inviting even more trouble. So I will consider other methods. Thanks a lot for your time and response.

Comment: `get_search_form()` is a mess. The same hook is used as an action and as a filter, and there is no real API.