# Shortcode or Template Page

Tags: shortcode, templates, page-template

When we have to add some functionality how to determine should I use shortcode or template file?

Ex : I need to add a page to enable front-end post submission.

I can do it creating a template page or using shortcode and add it to a page. How to identify what is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depends. If you're adding the functionality through a custom plugin or any third party solution rather than theme then the shortcode is best, otherwise you can use a template. You also can use template file with plugin, but then the theme and the plugin will be tightly coupled. That's kinda not preferred. But you can still do it.

Remember for shortcode, it's better to clean the output buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "it's better to clean the output buffer." ?

Comment: `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` etc. function. Just do a google search. If this answer helped you please accept it. @Damithatt

Comment: i actually heard it was better NOT to clean the buffer.  Can you show where you got that it was better.

Comment: I experienced it. And using it for a long time. Can you please give the reference where you heard that it should not be used with shortcode?

Comment: dude.  "experience"  isn't a reference or reason.  I'm on mobile so only did a quick one minute search but found this link readily that explains a very good reason no to use ob_start if you can avoid it.   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41012/proper-use-of-output-buffer.   additionally I think the best reason to use shortcodes is for ease of use for consumers to create dynamic content.

Comment: "dude", you've not read the full post. Please teach yourself to read the full post and understand the context first. dude here comes the term "Experience" which you don't have.  @rudtek

Comment: There is a comment you missed I think and that was **"This answer is a bit misleading. It ignores situations in which you can use OB just fine. For example you have a function that outputs some HTML, and you want to return that HTML. As long as you don't fire common actions or call WP functions like get_header() in it, you should use OB to produce more readable code."**

Comment: And now come to our context. Damithatt need to do a front end post submission and thus he need to render HTML. And without cleaning output buffer may cause some header warning. So please read any post first then understand the context and then comment or answer. And most importantly gather experience please. @rudtek

Comment: wow.  hostile much?  some one needs their medication.   I asked for references you didn't provide.  the link I sent states it's better not to use.  with which I agree.  that's all there is.  no need to be dramatic.